# How to config the Mate src in Freebsd

Tags: freebsd, mate-desktop

a favor is asked on the so-called "babystep" of the Mate configuration in Freebsd.

I understand that [here](https://github.com/jlmess77/mate-ports#mate-ports-for-freebsd) is the place for Mate install for Freebsd. But I should admit that I am a newer and I can't make sense of the "baby step" of editing the "
SRCDIR=" in the `matemerge.sh`.

Could anyone help me by letting me know what to input of the SRCDIR section? Is there a list to choose from?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, clone [mate-ports git repository](https://github.com/jlmess77/mate-ports) into some directory. Then, set `SRCDIR` variable (path to cloned `mate-ports` directory) and run `sh matemerge.sh`.

Note from the manual (github README):

> You will need to install the devel/git as matemerge.sh depends on it to fetch mate-ports from GitHub.